# Creating tiled JPEG using Lumia Imaging SDK

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, lumia-imaging-sdk, nokia-imaging-sdk

How can I create a bigger tiled image from a smaller image using the Lumia Imaging SDK on WP 8.1? I'm trying to use `JpegTools.BlendAsync()`([doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lumia.imaging.jpegtools.blendasync.aspx)), but I'm not sure it's the best way to do it.

Also, how do I read an image as an `IReadableBitmap`?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I create a bigger tiled image

Try [ReframingFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lumia.imaging.transforms.reframingfilter.aspx) to get bigger image and `JpegTools.BlendAsync()` just as you suggested (`BlendFilter` with `BlendFunction.Normal` would do the same I suppose).

> how do I read an image as an IReadableBitmap?

[StreamImageSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lumia.imaging.streamimagesource.streamimagesource.aspx) is what you are looking for. Get a stream, pass it to `StreamImageSource` constructor and you can get an `IReadableBitmap` with [StreamImageSource.GetBitmapAsync()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lumia.imaging.streamimagesource.getbitmapasync.aspx). Alternatively you can use [StorageFileImageSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lumia.imaging.storagefileimagesource.getbitmapasync.aspx) to achieve the same with a storage file.

Comment: I was able to create a tiled background using the `JpegTools.BlendAsync()` method, but I'm getting some unwanted separation lines at the boundaries of the tiles. Can you take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472176/lumia-imaging-sdk-image-blending-creates-separation-lines